# Modern frameworks method conventions

Tags: coding-standards, methods, conventions, method-chaining

I've been noticing that modern frameworks tend to have this kind of code style:

`expect(6 - 4).toBe(2)`

this can be rephrased as: `assert(6-4, 2)`

Yet the former is much more readable.

I would like to read more about this "style" of coding, but I have no idea what to search for. Does this convention have a name?

Thanks.

Comment: That's often called a "fluent" style.

Comment: :) thanks. If you put it as an answer, I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: related: [Coding style for chained function calls](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/210221/31260) and [What is the pattern name for using method chaining to build an object?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/137999/31260)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Some people may call it more [expressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expressive_power_%28computer_science%29), but "more expressive" means that you couldn't 1:1 replace it with another language's statements, which you do in your second example. So, the first example is not more *expressive*, but it is certainly more *fluent*.